# compare values from two regular expression extractors in JSR223 Preprocessor

Tags: jmeter

What is the best way to compare(manipulate) values from extracts in JSR223 Preprocessor without introducing performance degradation? JMeter is totally new tool for me.

I extracted values using two Regular Expression Extractors:

Extract1 has value1 and value2 (with Extract1_matchNr=20)

Extract2 has value3 and value2 (with Extract2_matchNr=80)

In JSR223 Preprocessor for same value2 I need to use pair combination of value1 and value3 from both extracts.

In Extract2 for each value2 there are about 4 unique values of value3 (I will randomly use just one value3 out of 4 values). 
In Extract1 both values of value1 and value2 are unique.

```
---Extract1:

    Extract1_1_g1=101 (value1)

    Extract1_1_g2=201 (value2)

    Extract1_2_g1=102

    Extract1_2_g2=202
    ....

    Extract1_n_g1=YYY

    Extract1_n_g2=ZZZ

    ---Extract2:

    Extract2_1_g1=301 (value3)

    Extract2_1_g2=201 (value2)

    Extract2_2_g1=302

    Extract2_2_g2=201 (same value2)

    Extract2_3_g1=303

    Extract2_3_g2=201 (same value2)

    Extract2_4_g1=304

    Extract2_4_g2=201 (same value2)
    ....
```

PS With one extract in other preProcessor I am using "for" loop to manipulate and concat values into myCombinedValues and use vars.put("pCombinedValues", myCombinedValues) for later use in other requests. 
all code samples I could find only use one extract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you use:

- [groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/)
- compilation caching
- don't reference JMeter variables as `${VAR}` inside Groovy script

There shouldn't be much overhead. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for more detailed information and scripting best practices.